# Waiting for process to terminate fails

Tags: process, automated-tests, terminate, testcomplete

I'm working on this function to wait for a WPF app to finish.

```
while (stillRunning)
  {
    if (timeOut > maxTime)
    {
      Log["Error"]("The App failed to shutdown correctly.");
      break;
    }
    else
    { 
      if (Aliases[process]["Exists"])
      {
        timeOut+=1000;

        if ((timeOut % 1000) == 0)
        {  
          Log["Message"]("The Application process is still running. " + (timeOut / 1000) + " seconds and waiting");
        }
      }
      else
      {
        stillRunning = false;
      }
    }
  }

  Log["Message"]("The Application process has been shutdown correctly."); 

}
```

Now, the thing is TestComplete 9 won't recognize when the application's been closed. I mean... I can clearly see how the process is not there anymore in Task Manager whereas TC keeps counting until it reaches the limit time (more than enough in this case).

Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code:

```
function test()
{
  var timeout = 5000;

  var startTime = GetTickCount();
  var pClosed = waitProcessClose("notepad", timeout);
  var endTime = GetTickCount();

  var closeTimeS = Math.round((endTime - startTime) / 100) / 10;

  if (pClosed) {
    Log.Message("The process was closed in " + closeTimeS + " seconds.");
  }
  else {
    Log.Warning("The process was not closed in " + (timeout / 1000) + " seconds.");
  }
}    

function waitProcessClose(processName, timeout)
{
  var endTime = GetTickCount() + timeout;
  var proc = Sys.WaitProcess(processName);

  while (proc.Exists) {
    var secondsLeft = Math.floor((endTime - GetTickCount()) / 1000);
    Delay(200, "Waiting for the '" + processName + "' process to be closed: " + secondsLeft);
    if (GetTickCount() > endTime) {
      Log.Warning("The process is not closed within '" + timeout + "' ms.");
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}
```

Comment: Hi Dmitry, thanks for you reply and the code. What I'm trying to do is to avoid the **WaitProcess** method, since I don't want any 'fixed' time. That would give me an idea of how long it took to close in every workstation.

Comment: The WaitProcess method by default works immediately and does not wait. If the sought-for process does not exist, the method returns at once.

Comment: I understand, but the goal is to have a function to be able to use it in different contexts. The method is OK for certain use, my function is intended to do more things like measuring how long would it take to open an close the application and posting warnings/messages in the middle.
This is the stripped version of the function without all that functionality, but even though it works exactly in the same way.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Now, the sample counts time taken by process to close. Is this what you need?

Comment: That's it! I'll try it today, but it looks promising! Thanks again